# CheckBoxList Placement

Tags: css, html, aspx-user-control

I have two CheckBoxLists on my webpage. I have tried to center them on the page. Nothing so far has worked. I wanted to know if it has to do with the table that is created on databind and if I have to somehow add attributes to that instead of formatting the TR and TD? Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried creating three td's, putting the checkboxlist in the middle td and setting the left and right td's margin to 25%. Did not work.

I have tried setting the `<td style="text-align:center;">`, this did not work either.

Comment: Don't use tables for layout -- it's 2015, for Pete's sake!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; height: 25px; line-height: 25px;">
```

Comment: It was the RepeatLayout that needed to be set. Setting it to Flow allows me to use the TD style to center. Now I need to figure out how to get some spacing between the check boxes in the list.